# Unable to populate array while using pandas_udf in PySpark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pandas-groupby, user-defined-functions

I have a PySpark dataframe, which is like

```
+---+------+------+
|key|value1|value2|
+---+------+------+
|  a|     1|     0|
|  a|     1|    42|
|  b|     3|    -1|
|  b|    10|    -2|
+---+------+------+
```

I have defined a pandas_udf like -

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("key", StringType())
])

arr = []
@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def g(df):
    k = df.key.iloc[0]
    series = [d for d in df.value2]
    arr.append(len(series))
    print(series)
    return pd.DataFrame([k])
df3.groupby("key").apply(g).collect()
print(arr)
```

As evident, the array arr should have been [2, 2], but it remains empty.
The output of print(series) looks correct when I checked driver logs, but the array remains empty.

The return type doesn't matter to me as I'm not changing/processing the data, I just want to push it in a custom class object.

Comment: could you try making arr global like `global arr=[]`?If it didn't work try to broadcast the variable  with `sc.broadcast(arr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to define a custom [Accumulator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.2/api/python/_modules/pyspark/accumulators.html) for a list and use it.

```
from pyspark.accumulators import AccumulatorParam
class ListParam(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, val):
        return []
    def addInPlace(self, val1, val2):
        val1.append(val2)
        return val1
```